# Tensorflow Estimator - gradually decreasing GPU utilization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training tf.Estimator model (5025056 trainable parameters):

```
# simplified code
model = create_custom_model() #preparing my model here 
tf.reset_default_graph()
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model.get_model_fn())
evaluation_hook = tf.contrib.estimator.InMemoryEvaluatorHook(
    estimator=estimator,
    input_fn=lambda: model.eval_input_fn()
)
estimator.train(
    input_fn=lambda: model.train_input_fn(),
    hooks=[evaluation_hook]
)
```

And dataset is prepared here:

```
def train_input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("some_filename")
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(3000)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(384)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
    return dataset
```

My dataset consists of images, 9000 samples, stored in TFRecord (163M). 
GPU is `GeForce GTX 1080 Ti` and CPU is `i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz`.
During the training, at first, everything looks fine - `htop` shows that each core is working approximately the same way (mostly jumping between `0` - `50%` utilization), and gpu stats (shown using `vidia-smi --query-gpu=timestamp,pstate,temperature.gpu,utilization.gpu,utilization.memory,memory.total,memory.free,memory.used --format=csv -l 1`) indicate that card is working on `100%` of its power - performance state P2, temperatures around `85°C`, `100%` utilization of gpu and memory, also most of the memory is used(10GB).
Up to step `4000` (of `10000`) tensorflow prints `global_step/sec` with values ranging from `1.0` to `1.1`. `15GB` of available `16GB` of RAM is used and no swap.

After that step, that time `global_step/sec` is lower and lower. For step `5000` it is `0.617275`.
Aaround step 2000 it is only `0.0938672` and decreasing (down to `0.0368357` at the end of the training). During this process `nvidia-smi` shows performance state P8, and `utilization.gpu` and `utilization.memory` is `0%` more and more frequently (despite the fact that `memory.used` shows same amount whole time, that is `10GB`), and CPU is working at a `100%` of a single core. RAM is at the same level as when training started, and no swapping occurs. Periodically, mayby once for `20` steps, GPU utilization is slightly higher, but quickly returns to `0`.

It looks like after some epochs tensorflow trains on CPU instead of GPU? What can be possible cause of that? TF version is `1.14.0`, before that, for `1.11.0` it was the same.